# ¿Como pedir permisos de internet en android 7?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

estoy con haciendo una app en la cual necesita hacer consultas a una página web, estoy intentando pedir los permisos de internet y no soy capaz de que me aparezca el mensaje, directamente me dice que no tengo los permisos, con lo cual no puedo hacer peticiones, se que no está realizando las peticiones debido a que e usado wireshark y e visto que el movil no esta enviando ninguna petición a mi servidor local

Esto es lo que tengo yo hecho

```
private void checkPermission() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "This version is not Android 6 or later " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        int hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);

        if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Requesting permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else if (hasWriteContactsPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            Toast.makeText(this, "The permissions are already granted ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    }

    return;
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if(REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS == requestCode) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "OK Permissions granted ! " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are not granted ! " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

E probado también de la manera habitual que es la siguiente

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 225);
    } else {

    }
```

Realizo la consulta al web service con la libreria volley

```
private void loadWebService(){


    String url = "http://192.168.1.130/register.php?name="+name.getText().toString().trim()+"&email="+email.getText().toString().trim()+"&password="+password.getText().toString().trim();
    url=url.replace(" ","%20");
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,this,this);
    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.UserRegistError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.UserRegist), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

el url.replace sobra aunque de todos modos no creo que el problema resida ahi

Comment: Revertí tu edición, pues me parece un intento de respuesta en la propia pregunta lo cual noes válido, con marcar una respuesta como aceptada o publicar tu solución alcanza. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solamente tenes que agregar el permiso al `Manifest.xml`.

Es un permiso con protection level `normal` así que te lo va a otorgar directamente, no necesitas pedirlo de manera "activa". De hecho si lo haces no va a ocurrir nada porque el permiso te lo concede en tiempo de instalación, no en Runtime, así que es en vano que pidas el permiso por código.

Los permisos tienen 3 niveles de protección:

- normal
- dangerous
- signature

Solamente para los permisos de nivel `dangerous` es necesario pedirlos en Runtime.

([documentación sobre Permisos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview))

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo deberías agregarlo al `Manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        ...

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Lo tengo puesto en el manifest, yo tambien pense que con el manifest seria suficiente

Comment: estas probando con un emulador o un device real? Estas seguro de que no tenes el servidor mal configurado y no le estan llegando peticiones?? Estas seguro de que tenes la app bien configurada para pegarle a tu instancia local?

Comment: Lo e probado con ambas ya que no estaba seguro en un principio de si era por el emulador, y si, el servidor esta corriendo correctamente y todo ya que si yo entro a la dirección puesta funciona

Comment: podes poner el codigo de como te estas comunicando con el servidor desde la app? y si tenes algun mensaje de Logcat mejor

Comment: clago edito la pregunta y asi lo ves mejor

Answer (score 0):

El permiso para uso de internet en tu aplicación no esta incluido dentro del **[grupo de permisos riesgosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html?hl=es-419#perm-groups)**.

Por lo tanto **para usar el permiso para acceder a internet es suficiente definirlo en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`**:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Unicamente los permisos de la siguiente lista que son considerados "Riesgosos", los cuales desde Android 6.0 (API nivel 23) deben ser requeridos de manera manual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa:

**[Solicitar permisos de la app](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419)**

**[Permisos del sistema](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html?hl=es-419)**